# magento - reindex category product position

Tags: php, mysql, magento, entity-attribute-value

I've developed a custom product sort module with drag'n'drop and, for simplicity and speeds sake, it updates directly to the EAV tables.  I save this new position with:

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$write->beginTransaction();

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($ids); $i++)
{
    $query = "UPDATE catalog_category_product SET position='".$i."' WHERE product_id='".$ids[$i]."' AND category_id='".$cat."'";
    $write->query($query);
}

$write->commit();
```

My question is how I can force a reindex on only the affected changes so that the position sorting is visible in the frontend.

I've tried to dispatch several different events like for example this:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_flat_rebuild', array(
    'store_id' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId(),
    'table'    => Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/category_flat')->getMainStoreTable(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId())
));
```

But I still see the old sort order in the frontend, and also this would reindex the full flat table, I would prefer to just reindex the array of Product ID's  and category ID that I changed position on.  Any ideas on how I would accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check if it is a caching issue? Restart server & clear browser cache, and see if it updates after that.

Comment: caching is off, this is my local developer environment

Comment: If you have a catalog_category_product_index table, try updating the position there

Comment: I did. But whats the difference?  Is that table monitored for changes perhaps?

Comment: Seems like it works, had to change to read from that same table too. I'll write back if there's any unexpected side-effects. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure about the explanation, I've had very little to do with Magento I'm afraid. Glad it worked out for you.